# Select List value in an If statement - Computed Field

Tags: entities

I have created a select list field in my Entity Form.

```
Select List : none||none and AM||AM and PM||PM
```

In my computed field, I want to know what did the user chose by using IF STATEMENT

example:

```
if($halfday == 'AM')
{
//action
}
```

I tried to use array_pop (example code :

`$halfday = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type,$entity,'field_halfday'));)`

but it does not work for me. What PHP code should I use? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following code under **Computed Code (PHP) texarea** in computed filed settings

```
$calc =  $entity-> field_sample['und'][0]['value'];

if($calc == 'AM')
{
 //action
$entity_field[0]['value'] = 'After Meridian';
}

elseif($calc == 'PM')
{
//action
$entity_field[0]['value'] = 'Prime Meridian';
}
```

This is a sample tested code which prints the selected item at output of computed field.

Note: replace `filed_sample` with your select list field machine name.